# Create rpm package using fpm with --after-install gives error

Tags: rpm, fpm

I'm new to linux packaging so I might be missing something obvious. I'm packing my program to `deb` and `rpm` packages and I'm using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to help me. I need people to enter their API key at the end of installation so that the configuration file could be updated automatically. I have a `blah.postinst` file that contains this part:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

read -p 'Please enter your API key(skip this step by just press ENTER): ' apikey_var
if [[ ! -z $apikey_var ]]
then
    echo "The API key is set. You could always change it by editing /etc/agent/process-collector.ini file"
    sed "s/sample_apikey/$apikey_var/" /etc/agent/process-collector.ini.example > /etc/agent/process-collector.ini
else
    echo "You didn't enter any API key, you could always add it by editing /etc/agent/process-collector.ini file"
    mv /etc/agent/process-collector.ini.example /etc/agent/process-collector.ini
fi
```

and I'm using fpm's `--after-install` flag to include this script.

This works for `deb` package, but after I use fpm to create `rpm` package and try to install it, the line `read -p 'Please enter your API key(skip this step by just press ENTER): ' apikey_var`(I think) yields error:

```
warning: %post(process-agent-0.99.0-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package dd-process-agent-0.99.0-1.x86_64
```

I would imagine that the code in `blah.postinst` script would just be fitting into the `%post` section of the `spec` file if I create an rpm package manually, but I can't figure out what could go wrong. Can anybody help on this? Or at least how do I debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed before; `rpm`s are designed to be *automated*. Do *not* expect a terminal to be there for interaction. It could be in another session (like `anaconda` or `puppet` would). It might be backgrounded. It may be a cron job. Have it collect the information on the first run or have them run a script noted in your "Getting Started" guide.

Comment: Cool, it's always good to have voice from people who know it well.